# Reading data organised in folders with Codename one

Tags: file, directory, codenameone

I've got data generated by a desktop application. These data are organized in a 2-levels folders system : each folder is a physical representation of one object, with an image file, a property file and different text files. There is no way I can change this structure.

I'm willing to show these data with a mobile application. I started something with Intel XDK, but I feel more comfortable with java.  So I'm building a POC with Codename One.  The final goal is to get these data on the mobile device with a DropBox integration. But for now (in dev phase), I'm going to manually download the data in a user folder on the device.

In netbeans, I put a sample of these data in the src/ folder, but when I try to read them, I've got an error telling me that nested directories are not allowed:

```
ERROR: resources cannont be nested in directories in Codename One! Invalid resource: /00002/page.properties
```

Any suggestion on how I can move on with the development, using with static folders ?

Answer (score 0):

Resource files must be placed in the root of the src directory to be packaged and can't be deeper. The reasoning is that we don't generate a JAR but rather a native package where hierarchies are pretty different.

If you need this exact structure just extract them into the `FileSystemStorage` on the first activation then you can use the hierarchy that's available there.